# Website displaying incorrectly in Linux OS

Tags: linux

My site written in Palatino Linotype a default font for Mac,Widows and Linux(so I Have read) has some headings displaying differently in Linux. This is an OS problem not a browser problem it renders in windows properly in five different browsers and the fault appears in Linux in the two of them that I have installed in Zorin 6.4 core. Anyone have any experience of this? I am untechnical so answers in simple language please.

Comment: Some screenshots will be useful for those trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Palatino linotype is NOT directly available for Linux.

check here https://mondaybynoon.com/linux-font-equivalents-to-popular-web-typefaces/

I advise you to read this piece on common compatible fonts: http://webdesign.about.com/od/fonts/qt/web-safe-fonts.htm

And lastly, an Ubuntu (you did not specify your distro) guide to get palatino installed : 
http://howto.praqma.net/ubuntu/fonts

As a rule of thumb, you should never ask a visitor to your website to install a font to see your content properly.